# browser-sync не запускается на тач устройствах

Tags: gulp, browsersync

когда на смартфоне в адресной строке ввожу

`External: http://192.168.42.173:3000`(без External)

нет доступа,

а так, в целом на десктопе все работает без каких либо нареканий.

Что интересное, когда указываю  `tunnel: true`  запускается на таче все идет норм, но приходится заново запускать `GULP` при каждом изменений странички,

Подскажите почему так, спасибо!!

Comment: Порт 3000 открыт?

Comment: как это проверить??